# What are the precise meaning of "in-law" terms?

Tags: noun

What is the exact definition of the in-law terms?

Note that Latin terms do not necessarily align with English terms. For example, Latin *patruus*, and *avunculus* are both English "uncle" (on the father's and mother's side respectively).

For each, it is not clear if the Ego (the sociological term for the person to whom the relative is related) can be male or female, and whether marriage ties (the "in-law"
link) extends through only one or also two marriages.

For example, it is not clear if *glos* can be:

- A male or female Ego's brother's wife
- A male Ego's wife's sister
- A male Ego's wife's brother's wife (brother-in-law's wife?)
- A male or female Ego's sibling's spouse's  sister. (This is a bit complicated, but "sister-in-law" is used this way in English.)

Can you clarify these terms?

1. *gener*, a daughter's husband, a son-in-law.
2. *glos*,  a husband's sister, sister-in-law.
3. *levir*, husband's brother, brother-in-law (Also, how does this relate to *sororius* and *socrinus*?)
4. *nurus*, daughter-in-law
5. *socer*, father-in-law
6. *socrinus*, brother-in-law. (Not in Lewis; Also, how does this relate to *sororius* and *levir*?)
7. *socrus*,  mother-in-law, rarely father-in-law
8. *sororius* of or belonging to a sister, sisterly. Perhaps used for brother-in law, the husband of Ego's sister. (Also, how  does this relate to *socrinus* and *levir*?)

Am I missing some terms here?

---

*Edit*

Following Sebastian Koppehel's helpful answer, the above definitions come from [Lewis' dictionary](http://www.perseus.tufts.edu/hopper/text?doc=sororius&fromdoc=Perseus%3Atext%3A1999.04.0059) (which does not clarify whether a term exactly aligns with the English X-in-law terms).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[**Glos**](http://www.perseus.tufts.edu/hopper/text?doc=Perseus%3Atext%3A1999.04.0059%3Aentry%3Dglos) and [**levir**](http://www.perseus.tufts.edu/hopper/text?doc=Perseus%3Atext%3A1999.04.0059%3Aentry%3Dlevir) are the husband's sister and brother. These are relatively obscure words. You might just as well (or better) say *soror/frater mariti* instead; the upside is that you can talk about the other half of the family just as easily: *soror/frater uxoris*. *Glos* can apparently also be a brother's wife, which can also be called *fratria*.

**Gener, nurus, socer, socrus** mean son, daughter, father, mother in law; these should be pretty clear.

**Sororius, -a, -um** is an adjective meaning “relating to a sister,” the masculine form can apparently mean a sister's husband or son in Late Latin. It does not relate to *levir* in any particular way.

**Socrinus** is not a word that exists in Latin, as far as I can see.

I do not think any of these words imply anything about the “Ego's” sex, except that *glos* and *levir* assume you have a husband, suggesting that the “Ego” will probably be female.

Comment: *Glōs* and *lēvir* definitely aren't borrowings. *Socrinus* for some reason only seems to show up in certain Latin-Dutch dictionaries (meaning 'wife's brother'), AFAICT; might be an old copyright trap?

Comment: @Cairnarvon You're probably right about the Greek, although Georges derives *levir* from δαήρ, but it is probably just a cognate. They are both apparently quite obscure, though.

Comment: @SebastianKoppehel Thank you. (1) is there a word for a wife's sister?  (I don't see it in your list.) (2) Can these terms extend two steps? Is a woman's husband's sister's husband also a brother-in-law, as it would be in English?